# Novell Groupwise 7 to Google Apps LDAP Password

Tags: password, encryption, g-suite, novell

So I am attempting to Migrate all our user account information from Novell to Google Apps using Google Apps Directory Sync, one problem I've run into is Password Encryption Method, I have no idea what Novell uses or if I am even using the correct field for the key. Any Thoughts?

Update: Screenshot
http://screencast.com/t/jKFzfVyCWk

Answer (score 1):

As sysadmin noted, if Universal Password is enabled in your eDirectory tree, then in your password policy, enable allowing Admins to retrieve the password and then use this tool instead:  [Dump UP tool](http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/Wiki.jsp?page=DumpEdirectoryPasswordInformationTool)  it will generate the LDIF of all the passwords for you as well, all ready to go.

If you have IDM licensed, there are a couple of third party driver for Google Apps.

Concensus Consulting sells one: [Google Apps driver](http://www.concensus.com/joomla15/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=18&Itemid=18)

There is a version from a company in Australia.[Cosmokey driver](http://www.cosmoskey.com/products)  Or you can use the SOAP driver and send the events yourself as suggested by Justin.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on a few things. First of all, the Novell Password can't be exported since it uses a one way encryption method. New passwords are entered, crypted, and the crypto-text is compared to the stored crypto-text. Universal Passwords are a newer extension of Novell passwords that use 3DES to store the hash, and is technically reversible. The key is stored on a non-exportable attribute on each server-object.

I do not believe there is a way to natively and directly sync passwords between Google Apps Directory Sync and eDirectory. However, if Apps Directory Sync can function in Batch Mode (I don't know the app, so I can't say), you might be able to make it work through cunning scripting.

There is a way to export clear-text passwords from eDirectory. You need to set your Universal Password Policy to allow Admins to "retrieve universal passwords". Once that is done, use a utility like this one:

http://www.novell.com/communities/node/1275/universal-password-retrieval-utility

To retrieve the clear-text passwords. With this, it may be possible to merge the output of this utility with an LDIF dump from eDir that Google Apps Directory Sync can then use for password sync.

*Update:* If you're lucky enough to be using Novell IDM, I believe there is a connector for that and Google Apps which will allow 'native' password sync. However, without it the above method is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative might be to use this SOAP solution. http://www.novell.com/communities/node/2542/synchronizing-users-google-apps-idm

Answer (score 0):

According to [this google support form posting](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Apps/thread?tid=512601c5f6fdfcc0&hl=en), you should use simple authentication.